# Using the mean value theorem, show that $ \sqrt{1+x} < 1 + \frac{x}{2} $ for $ -1 \leq x < 0 $

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for a conceptual understanding of the problem and how the theorem helps to solve it.

If I understand the mean-value theorem correctly, it says that the slope of the secant line connecting the endpoints of the interval $ (a,b) $ in $ f(x) $ is also the slope of a point $ (c, f(c)) $ that is contained inside the interval. All assuming that $ f(x) $ is continuous and differentiable in the interval.

And the problem is asking to show that one curve $ \sqrt{1+x} $ is under the line $ 1 + \frac{x}{2} $ in the given interval.

Why should I think, in the first place, that the mean-value theorem can help me to determine this inequality?

Comment: I know that you want a proof with the MVT, but just a comment to say that the inequality can be proved in a much simpler way. Indeed, for $-1 \leq x < 0$, one has $\sqrt{1+x} \neq 1$, so $(1-\sqrt{1+x})^2 > 0$, so $2+x - 2 \sqrt{1+x} > 0$, so directly $\sqrt{1+x} < 1 + \frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. You mean $  0 \leq \sqrt{1+x} < 1 $?

Comment: Well if you want. The only point is that $\sqrt{1+x}$ must be $\neq 1$ (so $x$ must be $\neq 0$), to have a strict inequality at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$$
Now choose $x\in[-1,0)$ and apply the MVT on $(x,0)$ so that we have some $t\in(x,0)$ for which
$$f'(t)=\frac1{2\sqrt{1+t}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+0}}{x-0}$$
But this is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2\sqrt{1+t}}\lt1+\frac{x}2$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't we consider $ t $ between $ [-1, 0) $ too?

Comment: No because I want to use the MVT on this interval. Note that $(x,0)\subset [-1,0)$.

Comment: I understand your procedure, but why should I think that the mean-value theorem can help to prove the inequality? I don't see how is conceptually related.

Comment: @Jon I have directly applied it here for such a purpose. You can use it to rewrite a quantity in a different way that allows an inequality to be shown immediately. In this case all I used after rewriting the expression was that $\sqrt{1+t}\lt1$.